# iAd no requests? Test ads displayed fine previously.

Tags: iphone, xcode, iad, ads

I have had my app on the app store for 2 days now and it hasn't made one request for an ad. During testing it displays test ads perfectly fine so they were working/code is correct. Also in the iAd network it shows 'This app is receiving live ads'. I have had downloads of the app and also had a friend download the app and test, so it would have requested an ad.

Any ideas why it would be making no requests? Does it normally take a few days before it requests any? I have heard of it taking a few days to make impressions, but not heard of it taking a few days to make requests... I'm sure my other apps have started requesting ads straight away (might be wrong!).

Answer (score 4):

Well it seems overnight it has started making requests and I am seeing impressions; therefore maybe iAd does take a couple days to start making requests. I thought I would let everyone know in case they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

iAds stopped appearing in my app 2 days ago all together but everything shows to be running normal

Comment: Seems like a blip with the Apple servers or something then. Glad to know it wasn't just me. All the best.